# Pepper's comment about Latin

Tags: dialogue, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-2

In Iron Man 2, Pepper and Tony are discussing Natalie and there's a discussion about Latin.  Pepper explains that you can read Latin but you can't speak it?

I thought Latin was commonly spoken in churches, law and medicine until very recently? So why did Pepper say that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, I don't remember the scene exactly, but I'm pretty sure, that this was meant rather sarcastic.

Latin is really not an easy language and has a rather complex grammar. Besides that it's not really spoken in everyday life anymore and only read from ancient texts or used in quite specialized contexts (law and medical terms, recitated prayers), but not spoken in direct dialogue. That's why it's commonly referred to as a *"dead language"*.

So what she probably means is, that somebody who claims to *speak* Latin (fluently) is either an impostor or some weird genius (or works in Vatican, which doesn't make it any better ;)).

Comment: Ah but Black Widow *can* speak Latin

Comment: Or, a time traveler!

Comment: You don't need to be a genius to major in the classics.

Comment: @DanNeely Indeed, but to speak and hear it freely in a dialogue is another thing than reading or writing it, I guess, where "thinking time" isn't that limited. It is just not that usual to find enough "practice situations". Pepper's comment (and  my answer) was maybe a bit over-generalizing, but I have yet to meet someone myself who can *speak* it fluently.

Comment: @ChristianRau  I think i see what you're getting at now. I've encountered a few people online who've claimed to be fluent in latin; but I don't have any way to verify their claims.

Comment: Jamie lee Curtis also tells Kevin Kline who says that 'Monkeys don't read Plato!', 'Yes they can, they just don't understand it.' in A fish called Wanda.

Comment: Or is a Latin teacher..  Latin is still often taught in private schools in the UK (quite why I do not know) - and yes it is spoken.  I have a (minor) qualification in Latin but do I remember or use any of it now .... no.

Comment: Yes I know it is still taught (it was taught to me, too) and used and there are even people who can **speak** it freely in spontaneous dialogue, it is just not that common compared to mere reading and writing. And I doubt a Latin teacher can really **speak** Latin instead of reading and writing it. And that's ultimately what Pepper (and I) was after.

Comment: My latin teacher used to try to converse with us in Latin and Ancient Greek - I used to hate Latin lessons.  Perhaps you are correct that most teachers wouldn't take it to that level.

Comment: @ChristianRau if there is any useful information in these comments, please incorporate it into your answer

Comment: @DForck42 No, there isn't, but thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

Latin certainly is still **spoken**, just not widely. From a [BBC article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-21412604), "Now retired to Milwaukee, Wisconsin, Foster **continues to speak to friends in the Vatican on the phone in Latin**". Foster (that is [Father Reginald Foster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Father_Reginald_Foster)) is also quoted as saying:

> Latin is a language, it didn't come down in a golden box from Heaven. You don't have to be clever to speak it. In ancient Rome it was spoken by poor people, prostitutes and bums.

He also runs a two-month immersion course in Latin, in which ["Two nights a week are dedicated to conversational Latin"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Father_Reginald_Foster#Latin_classes). However, he estimates the number of fluent speakers is very small, perhaps only around 100.

Answer (score 0):

Carpe Diem, Quid Pro Quo, Pro Se, In Vino Veritas, Semper Fi (short for Semper Fidelis)...  It's certainly spoken frequently enough as certain phrases have found their way into (almost) everyday life.  However, it's definitely not **widely** used anymore in full.